# How to avoid servlet converting a multidimensional array of string into one-dimensional array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, multidimensional-array

**Question**

I got a multidimensional array of strings which is sent from a jsp, when I try to get the array and set it to a variable in the servlet I realize the controller converts the multidimensional array strings into a one dimensional array of strings, I printed array in the console.log from the side of the jsp just to make sure the array contained arrays of string and not just strings and the log of chrome showed it was all ok, so I guess the issue must be in the side of the servlet. This is not an error but is not the behavior I was expecting for what I want to achieve next in my application.

Here is the code I have troubles with:

```
String[] arrayCompra = request.getParameterValues("arraycompra[]");
```

So basically what servlet is doing when I set the array from request to the one in servlet side is something like this:

```
String[][] array = { {"a","b","c"} , {"d","e","f"} };
```

Into this:

```
String[] array = {"a,b,c", "d,e,f"};
```

Additionally I searched for a solution and got with some answers and ideas like adding .clone(); but it gave me the same result. And I know there is a string.Split method but I would have to iterate in the array to split each string and then set each resulting array to the multidimensional array of strings, and I find it unnecessary if I can avoid or solve the main issue.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to achieve what I want? is there a better way to make an exact copy of the multidimensional array I'm getting from request in servlet?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

**Solution** *by Bohemian*

```
String[][] arrayCompra = Arrays.stream(request.getParameterValues("arraycompra[]")).map(s -> s.split(",")).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Btw... some methods of this solution required JDK 8 or higher and I was using 1.7 so I faced with...

```
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

> To solve this just change compiler version of your source code into your project properties to JDK 8 but first check whether you have one already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than fight the framework, here's a 1-liner that converts an array of CSV to a 2D array:

```
String[][] arrayCompra = Arrays.stream(request.getParameterValues("arraycompra[]"))
    .map(s -> s.split(","))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Comment: Hey it worked perfectly!! That's the kind of solution I was looking for but I didn't know how to implement. And to be honest I'd never have figured out how to do it this way. You have helped me a lot with this thanks a lot!